# If the coefficients of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx +c$ are u.i.i.d ran variates in $(0,1)$ what is the probability of roots being real?

Tags: probability

If the coefficients a,b,c(taken in order ,c being the constant term) of a quadratic equation are randomly and independenly chosen in the open interval(0,1) what is the probability that both the roots are real?

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask it as a new question: don't erase your previous question.

Comment: I apologise I will not do it again

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/probability-that-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

For every positive $x$, $P[c\lt x]=\min(x,1)$. Applying this to $x=b^2/(4a)$, one gets $$P[b^2\gt4ac]=P[4a\lt b^2]+E[b^2/(4a);4a\gt b^2].$$
For every $x$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
P[a\lt x]+E[x/a;a\gt x]=x+\int_x^1\frac{x}z\mathrm dz=x(1-\log x).
$$
Applying this to $x=b^2/4$, which is almost surely in $(0,1)$, one gets
$$
P[b^2\gt4ac]=E\left[\frac{b^2}4\left(1-\log\left(\frac{b^2}4\right)\right)\right]=\left.(1+\log4)\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^3}6\log x+\frac{x^3}{18}\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}.
$$
Thus, the probability $p$ that the two roots are real is
$$
p=P[b^2\gt4ac]=\frac1{12}(1+\log4)+\frac1{18}=\frac5{36}+\frac16\log2\approx25.44\%.
$$

Comment: how did you write $P(b^2 \gt 4ac)=P(4a \lt b^2)+E(\frac{b^2}{4a};4a \gt b^2)$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma The reason is stated one line before: $P(c\lt x)=\min(x,1)$ for every nonnegative real number $x$ hence $P(b^2\gt4ac)=E(\min(b^2/(4a),1))$, and $E(\min(u,1))=P(u\geqslant1)+E(u;u\lt1)$ for every random variable $u$.

Answer (score 3):

$a,b,c$ are limited to the interval $(0,1)$, so that
$$
P(b^2 < 4ac) = \int_{a=0}^1\int_{c=0}^1\int_{b=0}^{\min(2\sqrt{ac},1)}da\,db\,dc =
\int_{a=0}^1\int_{c=0}^1 \min(2\sqrt{ac},1)\,da\,dc,
$$
so that
$$
P(b^2 < 4ac) = \int_{a=0}^1\int_{c=0}^{\min(1/(4a),1)}2\sqrt{ac}\,da\,dc
+ \int_{a=0}^1\int_{c=\min(1/(4a),1)}^1\,da\,dc.
$$
The first integral is
$$
\begin{multline}
\int_{a=0}^1 2\sqrt{a}\,da\int_{c=0}^{\min(1/(4a),1)}\sqrt{c}\,dc = \frac{4}{3}\int_{a=0}^1 \sqrt{a}\min\left(\frac{1}{8a^{3/2}},1\right)\,da\\
= \frac{4}{3}\int_{a=0}^{1/4}\sqrt{a}\,da + \frac{1}{6}\int_{a=1/4}^1\frac{1}{a}\,da = \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{6}\ln(1/4)\tag{1}.
\end{multline}
$$
The second integral is
$$
\int_{a=0}^1 \left[1- \min\left(\frac{1}{4a},1\right)\right]\,da = \int_{a=1/4}^1\left(1 - \frac{1}{4a}\right)\,da = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\ln(1/4).\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
P(b^2 < 4ac) = \frac{31}{36} + \frac{1}{12}\ln(1/4),
$$
and
$$
P(b^2 > 4ac) = \frac{5}{36} - \frac{1}{12}\ln(1/4) = \frac{5}{36}+\frac{1}{6}\ln 2.
$$