# Probability of roots of equation are real

Tags: probability-theory

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $[0,9], [0,3]$ and $[0,5]$ respectively. What is the probability that both roots of the equation $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ are real?

I know I need $B^2>4AC$ but not sure how to get probability.

Comment: Hint: What is the probability distribution of $B^2-4AC$? And then, what is $P(B^2-4AC>0)$?

Comment: Ok, why 2 upvotes for this comment? Is the pdf of $B^2-4AC$ easy to calculate?

Comment: Just to make some connections: [29242](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242) is the node for the basic version with all three uniforms being in $[0,1]$. There are similar questions where the ranges of the unifs differ: [3182777](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182777), [3545048](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545048), and [877374](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877374).

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a rough sketch:
With a slight abuse of notation:

$|A| = 9-0 = 9$

$|B| = 3-0 = 3$

$|C| = 5-0 = 5$

First the probability distribution of $B^2$:

$P(B^2 < x) = P(-\sqrt{x} < B < \sqrt{x}) = P(0 < B < \sqrt{x}) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{|B|}$

$\implies f_{B^2}(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}\ |B|}$

Now consider:
\begin{align*}
P(B^2-4AC > 0) &= P(C<\frac{B^2}{4A})\\
&=P(C < \frac{B^2}{4A}, \frac{B^2}{4A} > |C|) + P(C < \frac{B^2}{4A}, \frac{B^2}{4A} < |C|)\\
&=P(C < |C|, \frac{B^2}{4A} > |C|) + P(C < \frac{B^2}{4A}, \frac{B^2}{4A} < |C|)\\ 
&= P( C < |C| | \frac{B^2}{4A} > |C|) \times P(\frac{B^2}{4A} > |C|) + P (C < \frac{B^2}{4A}) \times P(\frac{B^2}{4A} < |C|) \\
&= 1 \times P({B^2} > 4A|C|) + \int \int \frac{B^2}{4A|C|} \times P(B^2 < 4A|C|) dA dB
\end{align*}

Let $B'=B^2$
\begin{align*}
P(B^2 < 4A|C|) &= \int_0^{|B'|} \int_{\frac{B'}{4|C|}}^{|A|} \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{|B'|} \sqrt{A}\ dA\ dB'\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{|B'|} \int_0^{|B'|} \frac{2}{3} A^{3/2}\big|_{\frac{B'}{4|C|}}^{|A|} dB'\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{|B'|} \big(|A|^{3/2}B' - \frac{2}{5}\frac{B'^{5/2}}{(4|C|)^{3/2}} \big)\big|_{0}^{|B'|}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{|B'|} \big(|A|^{3/2}|B'| - \frac{2}{5}\frac{|B'|^{5/2}}{8|C|^{3/2}} \big)\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\int \int \frac{B^2}{4A|C|} \times P(B^2 < 4A|C|) &= \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{4|C||B'|} \int_0^{|B'|} \int_{\frac{B'}{4|C|}}^{|A|} \frac{B'}{A} \sqrt{A} \ dA \ dB'\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{4|C||B'|} \int_0^{|B'|} {2B'}\sqrt{A}\big|_{\frac{B'}{4|C|}}^{|A|} \ dB'\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{2|C||B'|} \int_0^{|B'|} B'(\sqrt{|A|}-\sqrt{\frac{B'}{4|C|}}) \ dB'\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{4|C|}}{2|C||B'|} \big( \sqrt{|A|} \frac{|B'|^2}{2} - \frac{2}{5} \frac{|B'|^{5/2}}{\sqrt{4|C|}} \big)
\end{align*}