# What's the probability that equation $x^2 + px + 6.9q = 0$ has real solutions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

> In the square $K = \{(u,v): u,v \in [0,\;9.6]\}$ randomly selected point with coordinates $(p,q)$. What is probability that equation $x^2 + px + 6.9q = 0$ has real solutions?

I was trying to solve this question, but I have no idea how to draw graph. Is there any easy way to solve this probability?
Any help appreciate, thanks.

Comment: A quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has real solutions when $b^2-4ac\geq0$. In your case, it is when $p^2-27.6q\geq0$, or $p^2\geq27.6q$. You can do a simple integral to find the probability.

Comment: Just to make some connections: [29242](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242) is the node for the basic version with all three uniforms being in $[0 , 1]$. There are similar questions where the ranges of the unifs differ: [3182777](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182777) ,  [3545048](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545048) ,  [1528677](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528677) ,  and [877374](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877374).