# Probability of real roots of a Poisson quadratic

Tags: probability, polynomials, poisson-distribution

> What is the probability that $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$ has real solutions if $a, b, c$ are Poisson variables with common mean $\lambda$?

This seems to require evaluating $P(b^2 - 4ac \geq 0)$, which is the sum $$e^{-3\lambda} \sum_{\substack{a, b, c \geq 0 \\ b^2 \geq 4ac}} \frac{\lambda^{a + b + c}}{a!b!c!}.$$ I'm not even sure how to begin evaluating such a thing though.

The question is straightforward if only one of the three coefficients is random, but even two makes it difficult. I would happily accept an answer to the question when, say, only $b$ and $c$ are random.

Comment: What information do you need about this probability, beyond just a formula for it? Is there any reason to think that sum has any kind of closed form representation?

Comment: My question was inspired by [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/probability-that-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots), where there was a very explicit answer. The Poisson is a "nice" discrete distribution, so it seemed natural to wonder if the same question had a similarly nice answer for it.