# Probability Quadratic Has Real Roots

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $A, B, C$ are positive, independent random variables with distribution function $F$. I am trying to show that quadratic $Az^2 + Bz + C$ has real roots with probability 
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty F\left(\frac{x^2}{4y}\right) dF(x)dF(y).$$

I know that I need to calculate $P[B^2 \geq 4AC]$, which would give me the answer I want, but I'm not sure how to do this.
I have tried looking for similiar problems, but the only examples I have been able to find, e.g. [Probability that a quadratic polynomial with random coefficients has real roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/probability-that-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots), are where $A, B, C$ have a uniform distribution. How can I extend to the general case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability that a quadratic polynomial with random coefficients has real roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/probability-that-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots)

Comment: @lulu That problem only deals with the case of a uniform distribution, whereas I am trying to work with a general distribution function $F$.

Comment: Ok, I'll retract the close vote.  Though the method of solution ought to be the same....just weight the measure appropriately.

Comment: @lulu I was trying to extrapolate from those solutions, but was having trouble doing so. I couldn't get the proof to work out properly. They seem to take advantage of the concreteness of the situation, (for example by taking derivatives of functions) which I cannot do here.

Comment: I'll give you a hint to get you started.  Clearly $x$ corresponds to $B$ because the appearance of $x^2$ in $F(x^2/(4y))$.  Now there is a symmetry whether you choose $y$ to correspond to $A$ or $C$, say $A$.  Then $F(x^2/(4y))$ corresponds to the probability of the other variable $C$ being ....

Comment: @user10354138 Is the second variable being taken to be $1$? How does that work?

Comment: No.  In $F(x^2/(4y))=P(C\leq \dots)$ what is the "..."?  Do you see how this all fits in $P(B^2\geq 4AC)$?

Comment: @user10354138 The ... is clearly $B^2 / 4A$. But how is the value of $C$ accounted for in the expression? Is it incorporated into the function $F$ - if so, how? This dependency doesn't seem clear, which I think is confusing me.

Comment: The cumulative distribution is the probability of $C$ at most that value.

Comment: I get it now, thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just for the record of discussion)

You want $\mathbf{P}(B^2\leq 4AC)$.  Since $A,B,C$ are positive, i.i.d. random variables with cumulative distribution $F$, we have
$$
\mathbf{P}(B^2\leq 4AC) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\mathbf{1}_{x^2\leq 4yc}(x,y,c)\,\mathrm{d}F_C(c)\,\mathrm{d}F_B(x)\,\mathrm{d}F_A(y)
$$
where the subscripts $A,B,C$ are there to decorate which random variable we are referring to.
Now $x^2\leq 4yc\iff c\leq x^2/(4y)$, so the innermost integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty\mathbf{1}_{c\leq x^2/(4y)}(x,y,c)\,\mathrm{d}F_C(c)
=\int_0^{x^2/(4y)}\,\mathrm{d}F_C(c)
=F\left(\frac{x^2}{4y}\right)
$$
which is the desired formula which you put the other integrals back.