# Do $3/8$ (37.5%) of Quadratics Have No $x$-Intercepts?

Tags: roots, graphing-functions, quadratics

I randomly had a thought about what proportion of quadratics don't have real $x$-intercepts. Initially I thought 33%, because 0,1,2 intercepts, then I thought that the proportion of 1 intercepts is infinitesimal. So I then thought 50%, as graphically half the quadratics would be above the $x$-axis, the other half below.

If you put it into a list of (max,min) and (above,below):
Minimum + Above = no $x$-intercepts

Minimum + Below = 2 $x$-intercepts

Maximum + Above = 2 $x$-intercepts

Maximum + Below = no $x$-intercepts.

Hence 50% right?

Well I simulated it using code. I randomised a, b and c, and output the discriminant. If it is less than 0, add 1 to a variable. Do this about 100000 times. Now divide the variable by 100000. I get numbers like $(37.5\pm0.2)$%.

I hypothesise that it averages $3/8$.

Why?

There may be a fallacy to my approach of finding the 'proportion'. Fundamentally, it is the probability of getting a quadratic with no $x$-intercepts. However, I am not sure.

**EDIT: The range was from $(-n,n)$, where $n$ was 100000, or even higher.**

Comment: For the case $a, b, c \in (0, 1)$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/probability-that-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots).

Comment: I should have mentioned, the range was from (-n,n), and I kept increasing n, no change in the output.

Comment: @Simplex1 since $a,b,c$ gives the same number of intercepts as $ka, kb, kc$ for any $k$, the results of your experiment *should* be independent of the range.

Comment: As an example of how there's not a natural probability distribution over quadratics - in my mind, it's equally or perhaps more natural to specify a quadratic in "completed square" form as: $A(x-B)^2 + C$. In this case, B marks the axis of reflection, C the y-coordinate of the extremal point.
If we take $(A, B, C)$ uniformly distributed in $[-n, n]^3$ then it's clear we have probability $1/2$ of an intercept because we have an intercept exactly when A and C are of opposite sign (ignoring the case of A or C being 0 which has probability density 0).

Comment: This was a great question, regardless of how it turns out.

Comment: @DavidE I see. I have assumed the form of a quadratic, however if I chose the turning point form then it would be different. The only issue is, with yours, A influences the value of the B term afterwards. (B->AB^2) so I do not believe it is really natural. But I get what you are saying.

Comment: The original question is ambiguous, but what if we followed @Simplex1's idea of increasing `n`? Would the proportion converge as `n` goes to infinity? In other words, what is the limit (if any) if we keep increasing `n` where a, b, and c are always chosen randomly from a uniform distribution of (-n, n)?

Comment: It's amazing how much people fuss about uniform distributions on the reals instead of taking the obvious interpretation of asymptotic density.

Comment: Seems to me that the number of possible quadratics for any non-discrete criteria is infinite, making it hard to state a ratio between the sizes of two infinite sets.

Comment: My bet would be on 0%

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret - true, although there's not a unique sensible asymptomatic distribution on the reals anyway (even in the context of a 'normal', changing $\sigma$ can affect your result if you're parametrising the coefficients of the quadratic).
However, my above comment about completing the square actually only requires that the $P(\text{A is of opposite sign to C}) = 1/2$ which is true for any symmetric probability distribution on A and C (I chose uniform for simplicity).
The key point that there is no canonical choice of a "random quadratic" without extra context still stands.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem isn't that there's no way to choose a random quadratic. The problem is that there's many ways, and there's no obvious reason to think of any of them as "the" way to pick one.

For starters, even picking a "random number" is something you can do in many ways:

- uniformly from some interval, say $(-1,1)$, or $(0, 1)$, or $(2,17)$,
- from a normal distribution with any mean or variance,
- from an exponential distribution with any mean,
- from a Cauchy distribution,
- from some weird arbitrary distribution you make up yourself

(Note that "a number uniformly randomly chosen from all real numbers" is *not* possible, simply because the integral of the density function over all real numbers (i.e. the total probability) must be $1$, and no constant function does that.)

Now, with that in mind, here are some ways you could pick a random quadratic:

- choosing each of $a$, $b$ and $c$ randomly by any of the above methods (or some combination of them) and constructing $ax^2 + bx + c$,
- choosing $(a, b)$ as the stationary point and a scaling factor $c$ (again, by any / several of the methods above) and writing $c(x - a)^2 + b$,
- choosing $f(0)$, $f(1)$, $f(2)$ randomly and using the unique quadratic that goes through all three (of course, you could replace $0$, $1$, $2$ with any other three real numbers),
- choosing $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, and $f''(0)$ randomly, and picking the quadratic that has those values (which is admittedly very similar to the first method, but not quite),
- ... I could go on.

All of these are plausible interpretations of "a random quadratic", depending on where the randomness is coming from. They will all (in general) produce different answers to questions like these.

(And note that for the same reasons as before, you can't have any way of picking random quadratics that is "translation-invariant" in the sense that $f(x)$ and $f(x - a)$ are equally likely, or $f(x)$ and $f(x) + b$ are equally likely.)

Now you could ask for your *particular* way of choosing a random quadratic, why the probability of having no x-intercepts is what you found it out to be. I think another of this question's answers points you in the right direction for that.

Comment: Those are technically accurate ways to define "Randomness" mathematically, but if you're asking "Out of all the quadratics, what proportion of them have this property", then you use a uniform distribution because you want a sampling so you're accurately representing the proportion of each type of quadratic that exists, where all quadratics are equally likely... The OP question doesn't make any sense at all with any distribution other than an uniform distribution.

Comment: @YungGun it sounds like you want the coefficients a, b, c, and c to be sampled uniformly from the real numbers. But this is impossible because there is no uniform distribution over the real numbers. The integral of a constant function on the reals is either zero or infinite, never 1.

Comment: @ThomSmith: I wouldn't be too sure of that. The limit of $\delta_a(x) = \frac{1}{\left|a\right| \sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-(x/a)^2}$ as $a \rightarrow 0$ is the Dirac delta function. What do you think the result of the limit as $a \rightarrow ∞$ is? Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: It converges to zero everywhere? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @Joshua: A constant function is just f(x)=c. You're overthinking this.

Comment: @Joshua The delta function isn't strictly a function since it's not a mapping $\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$; instead, it's a generalised function or distribution. Which, to be fair, you should have known if you'd read the article you'd linked. Thom Smith's point is still valid for all proper constant functions. Also, it isn't even *heuristically* constant everywhere, since it's a spike at $x=0$.

Comment: @Jam Well if you take the limit of the shaping variables in the opposite direction the spike goes away.

Comment: Yes but then it's identically the constant function $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @YungGun leaving aside the problem with uniform random reals for now, the trouble is that if you specify a random quadratic by uniform random coefficients, you will get a different distribution from if you specify one by uniformly randomly choosing a stationary point and a scale, and I can't see any justification for one of these being a more uniform distribution than the other.

Comment: Just so I understand this right. So mathematically we cannot even say that 50% of all integers are odd, because we cannot sample the infinite set of all integers in a representative way? Otherwise if we can find a "natural" way for the even/odd problem shouldn't there be a way to sample all quadratic polynomials like we can sample the natural numbers ?

Comment: @Falco There are reasonable ways to say 50% of integers are odd. They are not just very unique. You can look at the limit of the ratio of even to odd in $[0,n]$ as $n$ goes to infinity for example. That's probably where you get your intuition that 50% of integers are odd, it also gives you 25% or integers are multiples of 4 and so on. It's just not a very general method.

Comment: @Falco: If you take the positive integers in the order $2,4,1,6,8,3,10,12,5,14,16,7,\dots$, then $\frac{1}{3}$ of them are odd. But nobody would consider the positive integers in this order unless they were deliberately trying to construct a counterexample to something. On the other hand, if you asked 10 different mathematicians "what is the most natural way to construct a random quadratic", the procedures you'd get would probably lead to at least four different answers to this problem.

Comment: @Micah ok thank you I think I understand: So the problem is we have no natural ordering for all quadratic functions. But if we had a natural order for them, we could in principle answer the question.

Comment: @Falco: Partly it's about ordering, and partly it's about density (i.e., different ways of choosing quadratics might make certain kinds of quadratics more or less likely, and it's not clear which choice is correct). To continue the analogy, you could imagine that you're choosing a random positive integer, but in a way that makes integers ending in $7$ twice as likely, which means that more than half your integers will be odd. Again, nobody would ever do this for integers, but there's no compelling way to avoid it for quadratics.

Comment: @Micah this argument seems to prohibit the thesis "half of all real numbers start with an odd digit in their decimal representation" but it seems intuitively true just like with the integers.

Comment: If you find that intuitively true, you might find [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) interesting.

Comment: @Micah thank you for some interesting insights.

Answer (score 45):

It's helpful to think of each quadratic polynomial as corresponding to a point in "coefficient space", an abstract 3D space whose coordinates are $(a,b,c)$.  The question "What fraction of quadratic polynomials have no $x$-intercept?" can then be rephrased as "What fraction of coefficient space lies in the region $b^2 < 4 a c$?"

The problem is, of course, that this "coefficient space" has an infinite volume: $a$, $b$, or $c$ can be arbitrarily large.  What's more, the region of coefficient space corresponding to polynomials without intercepts is *also* infinitely large:  for any polynomial without an $x$-intercept, you can multiply it by any real number and get another polynomial without an $x$-intercept.  And if mathematics has taught us anything, it's that if we try to divide ∞ by ∞ we cannot expect a meaningful result.

You can, however, place bounds on the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$, so that these volumes of "coefficient space" are finite.  In your code, you picked the quantities $(a, b, c)$ with uniform probability from the range $(-10^5, 10^5)$.  This corresponds to the region of coefficient space below:

[image]

Mathematica (which I used to make this plot), tells me that the fraction of this cube that is filled is
$$
\frac{31 - 6 \ln 2}{72} = 0.3727932905... \neq \frac{3}{8}.
$$
So the ratio you found "experimentally" is not actually equal to 3/8, but it's pretty close.

On the other hand, you could have also decided to pick all your coefficients such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 < (10^5)^2$.  This would correspond to allowing $a$, $b$, and $c$ to lie in some spherical region of "coefficient space".  Spheres are nice, right?  Everybody likes spheres.

[image]

The fraction of this region out of the allowed spherical volume in coefficient space is (again, relying on Mathematica) is only about 0.3514..., noticeably less than 3/8.  The region of coefficients you allow, and how you parametrize them, turns out to make a difference in what your final answer is (which is what some of the other answers are trying to point out.)

Comment: Is the fraction dependent on the size of the structure?

Comment: @M.Herzkamp:  No, so long as you scale the volume uniformly in all directions.  This is because of the scaling properties I mentioned:  when $a x^2 + b x + c$ has no intercept, so does $k ax ^2 + kb x + kc$ for any value of $k$.

Comment: Does the sequence converge as the radius of the coeffecient space increases toward infinity?

Answer (score 27):

There are infinitely many quadratics, so the number you get in the end is completely up to how "sample" from the set of all possible curves. For example, if you sample $a\in[1,2]$, and $c\in[-2, -1]$, then *all* the curves will have a real intercept. On the other hand, if $a,c\in [1,2]$ and $b\in[-1,1]$, then *none* of the curves will have a real intercept.

**Edit**:

Now that you said that $a,b,c$ are all uniformly distributed on $[-n, n]$, your problem translates to this:

- Each selection of $(a,b,c)$ is one point in the cube $C=(-n, n)\times(-n, n)\times(-n,n)$.
- Each selection is equally likely.
- Therefore, you are really asking about the volume of the set $\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb C| b^2-4ac \geq 0\}$. Once you get that volume, the ration of that volume to the volume of $C$ is what you need.

Comment: Added the range to my question.

Comment: @Simplex1 What was the distribution? Uniform?

Comment: So would you suggest that there is no way to randomise it as the range is meaningless and arbitrary?

Comment: Yes it is uniform.

Comment: @Simplex1 No I would suggest that there is no way to "just randomize". You have to specify the range and distribution, but once you do that, it is perfectly meaningful to randomize. But you won't get an answer of "x% of all quadratics have a real intercept". You will get an answer of "If a random quadratic is picked in such and such way, then the probability of it having a real intercept is x%".

Comment: I see. Is my range/distribution well picked? If so then why is the output counterintuitively (at least to me) 37.5%.

Comment: @Simplex1 I don't know what you mean by "well" when asking if the distribution is "well picked". I mean, if we are simulating dice rolls, then we know that a distribution is "correct" if it fits the observed reality. What is your criterion of deciding what is "well"?

Comment: If it doesn't have a bias towards certain numbers, and it properly depicts a random set of coefficients.

Comment: What does "properly depicts a random set of coefficients" mean? I'm not trying to f*** with you here. I honestly don't know what you mean by that. That is, I know vaguely what you mean, but mathematics doesn't deal with vague meanings, we can only answer a question if we know *exactly* what it means.

Comment: If someone were to write down a quadratic equation (who theoretically no bias towards the values of the coefficients), are the values that I am simulating, of the same distribution as that person.

Comment: @Simplex1 I'm really not trying to be annoying, but what you wrote is not mathematically meaningful. "No bias towards the values of the coefficients" is meaningless.

Comment: It is supposed to mean that the numbers are distributed uniformly.

Comment: @Simplex1 Unoformly over *what*?

Comment: @5xum Over the reals within some finite range?... what else would it be? It's a uniform distribution including all reals within a range where each real is equally likely for each value of the coefficient. This method could be used to construct a uniform distribution of quadratic equations since each defining coefficient is uniformly distributed, could it not? He's just saying that each coefficient value in some range is equally likely. How is it not mathematically meaningful?..

Comment: @YungGun What "some" finite range?

Comment: @YungGun I guess the point is that picking coefficients uniformly at random between (-n, n) does not result in an unbiased, meaningful sample of quadratics[0]. And that actually, there is no way to define what an "unbiased, meaningful sample of quadratics" is, except maybe within a specific application or in the context of a specific problem. [0] And definitely not "uniform" distribution over quadratics - there exists no uniform distribution over $\mathbb R^3$ (or even $\mathbb R$ for what matters)

Comment: @Simplex1 I think David E's comment on the question makes it clear. You can uniformly pick *a*, *b* and *c* but then you are non-uniformly picking David's *A*, *B* and *C*. Or you can uniformly pick *A*, *B* and *C* but then you are non-uniformly picking *a*, *b* and *c*. You have to choose which numbers to uniformly pick, and that choice makes a difference.

Answer (score 16):

Assume $a$,$b$,$c$ are independent and uniform in $(-n,n)$. Denote the probability that the quadratic has no $x$-intercept by $p = P[b^2 < 4ac]$.
Since $b^2 < 4ac$ can only be true when $ac > 0$, which happens in $4$ of the $8$ possible sign assignments on $a,b,c$, and otherwise the condition is symmetric with respect to signs,
we have
\begin{align}
p
&= \frac{1}{2} P[b^2 < 4ac \mid a,b,c > 0] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} P[(b/n)^2 < 4(a/n)(c/n) \mid a,b,c > 0] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} P[y^2 < 4xz]
\end{align}
where $x,y,z$ are independent and uniform in $(0,1)$. In particular, $p$ does not depend on $n$.
The last probability is given by the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min\{2\sqrt{xz},1\}} 1 \; dy \; dz \; dx
= \frac{31}{36} - \frac{\ln 2}{6} \approx 0.745587
$$
[(Wolfram Alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_0%5E1+int_0%5Emin(2sqrt(xz),1)+1+dy+dz+dx). Hence
$$
p = \frac{31}{72} - \frac{\ln 2}{12} \approx 0.372793,
$$
very close to the conjectured $0.375$.

Answer (score 8):

While other answers have pointed out the problem of defining a random quadratic, I will argue that there are, indeed, rather interesting measures on the quadratics.

Let $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be the equation of a parabola. Il we multiply all the coefficients by some constant, we get e.g.

$$10ax^2+10bx+10c=0,$$

which is another equation of the same curve. Hence, instead of taking for $(a,b,c)$ general real numbers, we can normalize, for instance by adding the constraint $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$. Then $(a,b,c)$ lie on a sphere, on which there is a natural probability measure: the uniform measure. The simplest way to simulate this setting is to take for $a$, $b$ and $c$ three independent standard Gaussians; then $(a,b,c)/ \|a^2+b^2+c^2\|$ is uniform on the unit sphere.

Note that (as per Leftaroundabout's comment) this is just one possible normalization, and thus one possible measure on quadratics, called *Kac's random polynomial*. There are other reasonable measures. However, this one in particular gives rise to some interesting and not too difficult pieces of mathematics.

Anyway, whichever normalization you choose, this highlights a feature of this problem which is not very visible in Michael Seifert's answer: the quadratics having no $x$-intercept are exactly those whose coefficients satisfy $b^2-4ac<0$, which is, in parameter space, the equation of a filled cone (try to plot it on Mathematica and to move the object around). The point of view above interprets "the proportion of quadrics having no $x$-intercept" as "the proportion of directions in parameter space corresponding to quadrics having no $x$-intercept", or equivalently "the proportion of quadratics with $a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq 1$ having no $x$-intercept".

Under this setting, and if I'm not mistaken, a quick computation gives me that the probability of having no $x$-intersect is:

$$1-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\sqrt{t^4+4t^2+1}}{t^4+t^2+1} \ dt \simeq 0,351.$$

Reference : *How many zeroes of a random polynomial are real?*, A. Edelman and E. Kostlan, Bulletin of the AMS, Vol. 32, n.1, January 1995. Available on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9501224.pdf

The formula above is due to Kac (1943). I will let somebody else try to find a closed form, as there are poeple here much better than me at identifying and computing integrals.

Comment: This is an interesting way to look at it, but I disagree that this should be considered a “natural measure” on the space of quadratics. The sphere you're using is the Stiefel-1 manifold of the vector space of quadratics here, so far so good. But that vector space is per se not a Euclidean space; the Stiefel manifold is still defined but it is not a _unit sphere_. By using the monomial-expansion coefficients, you're picking an ultimately arbitrary scalar product which then gives rise to a measure on the Stiefel manifold as well.

Comment: @leftroundabout: good catch, and you are completely right. I've modified my answer to highlight this kind of choices (turning things a bit differently -- the Euclidean structure is still there, but then there is an arbitrary choice of embedding of the sphere into the Euclidean space).

Comment: This is $1/(2 \pi)$ times the solid angle of an oblique circular cone with base radius $2$, height $1$ and the distance between the center of the base and the foot of the altitude equal to $\sqrt 3$. There is a known formula for the solid angle, which gives
$$1 - \frac \alpha {2 \pi} K(1 - \alpha^4) -
 \frac {\alpha^5} {2 \pi} \Pi(1 - \alpha^8, 1 - \alpha^4)$$
in terms of $K(m)$ and $\Pi(n, m)$, where $\alpha = \sqrt {2 - \sqrt 3 \hspace {1px}}$.

Answer (score 5):

Since you used a computer, $a, b, c$ must have been in a restricted range.  Try altering that range and see how it affects your answer.  Even if you have a super computer with an enormous but still finite range of numbers, it will still tell you nothing about the case for all numbers.

Even a dream computer without limits would have a problem as you cannot pick evenly from an infinite set.

Consider a simpler problem: what proportion of positive integers have a digit $9$ in them?  The super naive answer is $10\%$ but even going as far as $100$ gives the larger answer $19\%$.  Now go to $1000$, $10000$, etc and you will find that the answer continues to grow.  It is easy enough to prove that it grows without limit and approaches $100\%$.  So, in a sense, $100\%$ of positive integers have a digit $9$.

Comment: Lets say he tests all numbers from (-100, 100), then (-1000, 1000), then (-10000, 10000), until he reaches 500 zeros. If all of those give you the same answer, then isn't it very highly likely you will get that answer no matter what numbers you choose? We can't know for sure if the answer is right, but we can know to a very high degree of probability can't we? Also, saying that the limit approaches 100% for the infinite series of numbers is not the same as saying the chance is 100% at any point, which is what you're saying when you say 100% of integers have a 9. It's untrue mathematically

Comment: No, whatever your finite limit is, however huge, it is still an insignificant fraction of all numbers.  For example, before Wiles' proof of Fermat's theorem, it was known that any exception would be very large.  However, this was not considered a proof.  Another thing to note is that if there are infinitely many possibilities then $100\%$ is not the same as certain.

Comment: @YungGun see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples.

Comment: @ThomSmith Thanks.  I was considering tracking down some examples but that link is perfect.

Comment: The answer by nomadictype proves that the range does not influence the result. I don't see how your answer adds value.

Comment: I'll accept that others, e.g. the accepted answer, have made my point better but I don't feel that mine is wrong.  The point that many of us were trying to make is that any finite sample of an infinite space is insignificant.  What nomadictype shows is that with one more precise interpretation an answer is possible.  That is also a good point but does not contradict the other point

Comment: nomadictype's samples are all cubes.  D. Thomine uses another attractive approach and gets a different answer.  That's the point.  You cannot sample the whole infinite space uniformly.  Different restrictions or distributions may give different results.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have done a good job at showing this mathematically, but I feel that a bit of visual explanation would help to solidify exactly why there is a difference in these two answers of $1/2$ and ~$3/8$.

Below, I have made a graph of all quadratic equations of the form $a(x-b)^2 +c$, for every combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$ in the closed interval $[-4,4]$, with a step size of $0.5$. The exact numbers are not relevant to this answer (though it is relevant to say that the x-scale and y-scale are equal, and both are linear).

For each parabola, I've only plotted a small section near the vertex. The line of each is colored according to how many x-intercepts it has: 0 is red, 1 is grey, and 2 is blue.

[image: graph of the search space for a(x-b)^2 +c]

A visual inspection reveals that there is roughly an equal number of red and blue parabolas, and both vastly outnumber the grey ones. The exact counts in this graph are:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{blue}{\text{Two}} & 2448 & 0.4982699 \\
\color{gray}{\text{One}} & 289 & 0.05882353 \\
\color{red}{\text{Zero}} & 2176 & 0.4429066 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Now, let's look at the same search space, but using the form $ax^2 +bx+c$. The graph looks quite different:

[image: graph of the search space for ax^2 +bx+c]

Again the grey are outnumbered, but we see vastly more blue than red. The exact numbers here are:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{blue}{\text{Two}} & 3104 & 0.6317932 \\
\color{gray}{\text{One}} & 65 & 0.0132302055 \\
\color{red}{\text{Zero}} & 1744 & 0.3549766 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

As we can see, the 'wings' of this graph are exclusively blue, meaning that all such parabolas have two intercepts. This is what skews the result away from $1/2$.

---

For those interested, the language I used to generate these images was [Processing](https://processing.org/), and the code may be found here: https://pastebin.com/geLya3jQ. (Why? Mostly because I don't have much experience with Mathematica, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

We need the probability that $b^2 < 4ac$. When $a$ and $c$ have opposite signs this condition is never satified; this occurs in 4 of the 8 octants of the problem domain. So we need only look at the other 4 octants. These are all related by symmetry, so we can choose one representative. Here we'll choose the octant $a \in [0,n], b \in [0,n], c \in [0,n]$. The relevant volume of the domain is given by

$$V = \int_{a=0}^n \int_{c=0}^n \int_{b=0}^{2\sqrt{ac}} \,{db} \,{dc} \,{da} $$

Carrying out the integration

$$V = \int_{a=0}^n \int_{c=0}^n {2\sqrt{ac}} \,{dc} \,{da} $$

$$V = \int_{a=0}^n \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{a} n^{3/2} \,{da} $$

$$V = \frac{8}{9} n^{3/2} n^{3/2} $$

This is the volume of one octant; the volume for the 4 octants is then

$$V = \frac{32}{9} n^{3} $$

The volume of the entire domain is $(2n)^3 = 8n^3$

Then the probability of having no x-intercept is

$$p=\frac{\frac{32}{9} n^{3}}{8n^3} = \frac{4}{9} $$

Note that the probability is independent of $n$.

Comment: Note that we could have $2\sqrt{ac}>n$ even if $a \le n$ and $c \le n$. So your integral isn't computing the volume of the correct region, but of something bigger. Perhaps this is why you've come up with a larger fraction than the OP...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different take on your question.

A quadratic equation (y=ax^2+bx+c) represents a parabola that opens either up or down -- never to the side or at an angle.  A quadratic equation has real roots if and only if the parabola that it represents touches or intersects the X-axis.

A parabola is the set of all points that are equidistant from a fixed point the nearest point on a line.  Since a quadratic equation defines a parabola that opens up or down, its line is necessarily horizontal: y=s for some constant s.

Due to this definition, a parabola defined by a quadratic equation can be uniquely identified by three parameters: the (x, y)=(q, r) coordinates of the fixed point (the focus) and the y=s coordinate of the horizontal line.

The x coordinate of the focus (q) is unimportant for this question as it has no bearing on whether the parabola intersects the X-axis.  So we're left with just r and s.

If r==s, then our parabola is in fact a straight line which cannot be described by a quadratic equation.  So we can discount this possibility.

If r > s, then the parabola opens upward.  The quadratic equation that describes it has real roots if (r+s)/2 >= 0.  If r < s, then the parabola opens downward.  The quadratic equation that describes it has real roots if (r+s)/2 <= 0.

After manipulating those equations a bit, the probability that we seek is P[r >= -s | r>s] + P[r <= -s | rs is equal to the probability that rs] is 0.5, so P[r >= -s | r>s] is 0.25.  Likewise, P[r <= -s | r