# Probability that $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$ where $a,b,c$ are normally distributed (numerical integration)

Tags: probability, integration, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, discriminant

I would like to determine the probability that a random quadratic polynomial has positive discriminant, where the 3 coefficients $a, b, c$ are normally distributed and independent:

> That is, given $a,b,c \sim \operatorname{N}\left(0,1\right)$, what is ( a numerical approximation to 5 digits of )
> $\operatorname{Pr}\left(\,{b^2 - 4 a c \geq 0}\,\right)$ ?

---

**Thoughts**:

We have

$$
\mathrm{Pr}\left(\,{b^2 - 4 a c \geq 0}\,\right)
=
\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\pi}\right)^3} \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathbb{\large 1}_{b^{2}\ -\ 4ac\ \geq\ 0}\quad{\rm e}^{-a^2}
{\rm e}^{-b^2}{\rm e}^{-c^2}\,\mathrm{d}a \,\mathrm{d}b \,\mathrm{d}c
$$

This integral probably cannot be expressed explicitly, but even a numerical approximation is not so easy. Here is what I tried with [SAGE](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), without success:

```
var('a,b,c') 
RR = RealField(100)
 
I = integrate(integrate(integrate(exp(-a^2), a, 0, b^2/(4*c)) * exp(-c^2),    c, 0, oo) * exp(-b^2),    b, 0, oo) print(RR(I)) #error...
```

Expermenting with SAGE seems to give a probability between 0.64 and 0.65 (compare the values given below if $a,b,c$ are uniformly distributed):

```
N = 0
T = 10^5
for _ in range(T):
    a = gauss(0, 1)
    b = gauss(0, 1)
    c = gauss(0, 1)
    if b^2 - 4*a*c >= 0:
        N += 1

print(float(N/T))
```

---

**Other comments**:

1. The idea to consider the normal distribution is that the vector $(a, b, c) / \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere, because the joint Gaussian distribution is spherically symmetric, and the property $b^2 - 4 a c \geq 0$ is invariant under rescaling.
2. Note that when $a,b,c \sim \mathrm{Unif}(-N, N)$ for some $N > 0$, the probability $\mathrm{Pr}(b^2 - 4 a c \geq 0)$ can be computed explicitly  [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818919): it is
   $$(41 + \log(64))/72 \approx 0.627207.$$ See also [Probability that a quadratic polynomial with random coefficients has real roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29242) for the case $a,b,c \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0, 1)$.

Comment: One might think that if $N(0, 1)$ were replaced with $N(0, \sigma^2)$ that would change the probability.  But it does not, because $b^2 - 4ac$ is a homogeneous polynomial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose we knew the expected number $\Bbb E$ of real roots of a random quadratic polynomial $aX^2 + bX + c$, where all $3$ coefficients have standard normal distribution, $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Then, if $\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0)$ is the probability that the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ of such a polynomial is positive, by definition
$\Bbb E = 2 \cdot \Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) + 0 \cdot \Bbb P(\Delta < 0) = 2 \Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0)$, so $$\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) = \frac12 \Bbb E .$$

On the other hand, a clever argument of Edelman and Kostman that identifies a polynomial $c + b t + a t^2$ with the vector $\langle c, b, a\rangle \in \Bbb R^3$ and considers the projection of the so-called moment curve $\gamma(t) = \langle 1, t, t^2 \rangle$ in $\Bbb R^3$ to the unit sphere shows that the expected number $\Bbb E$ of real zeros is $\frac1\pi \vert\gamma\vert$, where $|\gamma|$ denotes the arc length of $\gamma$. The arc length formula gives
$$
\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0)
= \frac12 \Bbb E
= \frac{|\gamma|}{2 \pi}
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2 - 1)^2} - \frac{9 t^4}{(t^6 - 1)^2}} \,dt
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t^4 + 4 t^2 + 1}}{t^4 + t^2 + 1} \,dt .
$$
Integrating numerically gives
$$
\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) = 0.64851\ldots}} ,
$$
in agreement with the Monte Carlo approximation that o.p. mentions. Even with some coaxing Mathematica wouldn't compute a form for the integral in terms of special functions, though I suspect that one can express the probability in terms of elliptic integral functions.

The integral expression for $|\gamma|$ specializes a [formula of Kac](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KacFormula.html) (1947). Both the above formula and the argument are actually given in the reference for polynomials of arbitrary degree. For cubic polynomials, the analogous computation gives the probability
$$\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{(t^2 + 1)^4 + 4 t^4}}{(t^4 + 1) (t^2 + 1)} \,dt - \frac12 = 0.24637\ldots .$$

**Long remark** When constructing a distribution on random polynomials of degree $\leq n$ in terms of their coefficients, at least for some purposes it's more natural to choose the coefficient of the degree-$k$ term to have variance $n \choose k$ times that of the leading and constant coefficients. See, for example, the discussion in $\S$3.1 of the reference.

For $n = 2$, we have $a, c \sim N(0, 1)$ and $b \sim \mathcal N(0, 2)$. For this distribution we can proceed by choosing a linear change of coordinates adapted to the geometry of the problem and a performing a simple geometric computation in those coordinates. In the coordinates $$(x, y, z) := \left(\frac{-a + c}{2}, \frac{b}{2}, \frac{a + c}{2}\right), $$

- the joint probability distribution is $$f(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{\pi^{3 / 2}} e^{-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}$$ and in particular is spherically symmetric, and
- the discriminant condition $\Delta \geq 0$ becomes
  $$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 \geq 0, $$ which is still invariant under dilation.

So, the probability that the discriminant is nonnegative is the probability that a randomly chosen point on a sphere centered at $(0, 0, 0)$ is outside the standard cone $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$, and a standard exercise gives that this probability is $$\boxed{\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} =  0.70710 \ldots} .$$

The analogous computation for $n = 3$, where the coefficients of $a, b, c, d$ of $a X^3 + b X^2 + c X + d$ have variances $1, 3, 3, 1$, respectively, gives $\Bbb P(\Delta \geq 0) = \frac12 (\sqrt 3 - 1) = 0.36602\ldots$.

> A. Edelman, E. Kostlan, ["How many zeros of a random polynomial are real?"](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1995-32-01/S0273-0979-1995-00571-9/) *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* **32** (1995), 1-37.

Comment: We can indeed give the integral in terms of elliptic functions: $$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t^4 + 4 t^2 + 1}}{t^4 + t^2 + 1} \,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi }\left(\left(1+\sqrt{3}+(5+3\sqrt{3})i\right) \Pi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}+\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)i}{2}\, \Bigg| -2\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)\right)+\left(1+\sqrt{3}-\left(5+3\sqrt{3}\right)i\right) \Pi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}-\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)i}{2}\,\Bigg| -2\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)\right)\right).$$ Here $\Pi(n|m):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\left(1-n\sin^2\theta\right)\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A relevant link is https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KacFormula.html . I think you meant "n = 4" before your sentence "the analogous computation gives the probability […]"

Answer (score 13):

It is known that the pdf $f_{ac}$of the product of two independent random variables $a$ and $c$ with standard normal distribution is (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2471397/1231520)):

$$f_{ac}(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}K_0(|t|), \quad t\in \mathbb R$$

where $K_0(t)$ denotes [the modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

Then, the probability can be obtained as follows:

$$\mathbb P (b^2 \ge 4ac)=\mathbb P \big (b^2 \ge 4ac, \, ac \le 0\big)+\mathbb P \big(b^2 \ge 4ac, \, ac>0 \big)=\\ \frac{1}{2}+\mathbb P \big (b \le -\sqrt{4ac}, \, ac>0 \big)+\mathbb P \big(b \ge \sqrt{4ac}, \, ac>0\big)=\\ \frac{1}{2}+2\int_0^\infty \left (1-\Phi\left(2\sqrt{t} \right) \right )\frac{K_0(t)}{\pi}\text{d} t= \\ \frac{1}{2}+\color{blue}{\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \left (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \right )K_0(t)\text{d} t}\\
 \approx \color{blue}{0.6485118}$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution and $\text{erf}$ is [the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), with $$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right).$$ The blue integral is numerically computed [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B%5C%2840%291-erf%5C%2840%292Divide%5BPower%5Ba%2C0.5%5D%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29Divide%5BBesselK%5C%2891%290%5C%2844%29a%5C%2893%29%2CPi%20%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D%20). The probability $0.6485118$ is very close to what is obtained by simulation in the OP.

Comment: It should be $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{2t}\right)\right)K_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2t}\right)K_0(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: @KStarGamer thanks for your help. I just fixed the typo of missing $\frac{1}{2}$ before erf. In the link you may see that I used the correct formula for computing the integral.

Comment: All good. For what it's worth, the given integral can actually be given in terms of elliptic functions: namely $$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \pi }\Re\left(\left(1+\sqrt{3}+(5+3\sqrt{3})i\right) \Pi \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}+\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)i}{2}\, \Bigg| -2\left(3+2\sqrt{3}\right)\right)\right),$$ where $\Pi(n|m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the third kind with the modulus $k^2=m$. We can transform the $\mathrm{erfc}$ form into a form involving radicals like in the other answer through Laplace transform techniques and evaluate that integral in terms of elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 5):

Just another presentation of the problem. Denote $$B=\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{2}}, C=\frac{b-c}{\sqrt{2}}$$ You are interested in $\Pr(X>0)$ when $X=\frac{B^2}{2}-\frac{C^2}{2}-4A^2$ where $A,B,C$ are independent $N(0,1).$ The characteristic function of $X$ is $$\varphi(t)=E(e^{itX})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-8it}}$$ with a suitable interpretation of $\sqrt{1-8it}.$ Since $\varphi$ is integrable, inversion formula applies and the density of $X$ is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_Re^{-itx}\varphi(t)dt$$ and for $T>0$ we have by Fubini
$$\Pr(0<X<T)=\int_0^Tf(x)dx=\int_R\frac{1-e^{-itT}}{it}\varphi(t)dt.$$

Comment: Using the idea used for representation, one can find the characteristic function of the product of two random variables with joint normal distributions:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835511/1231520.